# Sync iPod Shuffle 5th gen. with Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sync, ipod

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to sync my iPod Shuffle 5th gen. with Rhythmbox or other suitable program. Can you please advise?
Rhythmbox does recognize iPod however when it prompts me to initialize the iPod, the initialization itself does not happen. The program does not react to the action and Rhythmbox looses the connection with iPod.

Comment: Did you try the [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org) player? It detects my (very old) 1.0 GB silver 2nd generation iPod Shuffle. Just start a new terminal window (which you can start by holding the **Ctrl** **Alt** and **T** keys), then either install Clementine by issuing the command `sudo snap install clementine` (which is the **recommended** method, because it installs the most up-to-date Clementine version available at the Snap Store) or (if the `snap` command doesn't work) by issuing the command `sudo apt install clementine -y`. Clementine detects and shows mounted iPods.